# Ошибка OSError: [Errno 107], не знаю как исправить

Tags: python, сокет

вот код сервера:

```
import socket
import time
import threading

name = []

def pol():
    while True:
        try:
            user, adress = server.accept()
            print("подключился",adress)
            user.setblocking(0)
            player.append(user)
            print(user)
        except:
            pass

def polu():
    while True:
        for x in player:
            try:
                msg = x.recv(1024)
                print(msg)
                msg = msg.decode()
                print(msg)
                sen(msg=msg, ot=x)
            except:
                pass

def sen(msg, ot):
    for x in player:
        if not x == ot:
            x.sendall(msg.encode())
        else:
            pass


server =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY,1)
server.bind(("192.168", 5001))
server.setblocking(0)
server.listen(10)
player = []
print("сервер активен")

v = threading.Thread(target=polu)
v.start()
t = threading.Thread(target=pol)
t.start()
print("localhost")
while True:
    n = input()
    for y in player:
        try:
            y.sendall(n.encode())
        except:
            player.remove(y)
            y.close()
        print(y)
    time.sleep(1)
```

вот код клиента:

```
import socket
import threading
def prov():
    while True:
        msg = client.recv(1024)
        msg = msg.decode()
        print(msg)

client =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY,1)
try:
    client.connect_ex(("62.217",5001))
except:
    print("сервер выключен")
    input()
    exit()
    input()
p = threading.Thread(target=prov)
p.start()

b =  input("ваше имя") + ":  "

while True:
    client.sendall((b + input()).encode())
input()
```

Я хотел сделать онлайн чат. Получаю такую ошибку у друга. Если запускать на своём компе оба кода  - всё работает, но если запустить сервер у меня, а клиент у друга, то код не работает.

вот ошибка:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (prov):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, 
in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, 
in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/Danya998pop/test.py", line 5, in prov
ваше имя    msg = client.recv(1024)
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Comment: Приведите **полный стек-трейс ошибки прямо в вопросе**. Без трейса многое непонятно, текста ошибки недостаточно. А так то наверное на раутерах нужно порты ещё открыть, обычно они закрыты. А то и `IP` может быть динамическим. Кстати, `192.168.0.*` - это **внутренний** `IP-адрес`, снаружи его не видно. Для начала посмотрите, какой **внешний** адрес у вашего сервера и проверьте, идёт ли до этого адреса `traceroute` от клиента.

Comment: я только недавно зашёл на stack overflow и не знаю как редактировать вопрос

Comment: @ДаняАрхипов, чтобы редактировать вопрос, нажмите кнопку [edit] под вопросом.

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил ошибку и изменил айпи на внешний

Comment: @CrazyElf всё также не работает, и как проверить открыты ли порты

Comment: я открыл порты но ничего не работает

Comment: Так у сервера тоже `IP` надо на внешний поменять, а не только у клиента. `traceroute` то до этого `IP` доходит? Ещё можете попробовать `telnet` на этот адрес и порт.

Comment: @CrazyElf я меняю на внешний но пишет ошибку      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\server.py", line 42, in <module>
    server.bind(("62.217.189.249", 50001))
OSError: [WinError 10049] Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен

Comment: Ну тогда я дальше не знаю, я в сетях не спец. По идее должно быть так. А вы с нулём лишним в порту не ошиблись? Всё-таки `5001` или `50001`?

Comment: нет у меня 50001 но в коде я поменял на сайте нет

Comment: но почему ошибка когда я пишу внешний ip в bind?

Comment: Так, кажется я неправильно подсказал. Возможно, у сервера всё же нужно писать внутренний `IP`. Или как вариант попробуйте `0.0.0.0` в качестве `IP`, это вроде значит "слушать любые адреса компьютера. А вот клиент точно должен на ваш внешний `IP` обращаться.